# ASP.NET Server Control - Is shared Viewstate between controls possible

Tags: asp.net, viewstate, custom-server-controls

If I have a master 'composite custom server control', with several child custom controls, is it possible, for the master control to share its viewstate with the child controls, which are also custom composite server controls,(all of the controls are composite custom server controls)?

To expand a little more, say I have a *Person* control, *Address* control, *Phone* control and *Notes* control. *Address*, *Phone* and  *Notes* can exist as either independant controls, or as part of the *Person* control. Since each control is responsible for its own viewstate, and stores required data in it, so it can render/postback etc, it ends up that there is a lage duplication in the viewstate, since the Person control stores all the data, and then each child control stores its own data again. Also, to further complicate things, the *Person* Control adds the child controls dynamically, so its possible to add a 2nd address/phone number/note etc,which can cause yet a larger viewstate(up to 1MB).

In the case of when all the *Address/Phone/etc* controls are children of the the *Person* Control, is it possible for me to somehow share common viewstate data, so I dont have 2/3/4 copies of some stuff in the viewstate, and when they are not components, just act as normal?

I do have one idea for a solution, but its fairly nasty imo, where I could modify the *Person* control, expose its viewstate or the data, and then in the child control, would check the control hierarchy, and if the child control is part of a *Person*, dont use to its own viewstate, use the exposed one. This would require me to rework alot of the existing code, which I'd rather avoid if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first question I'd ask is, "How much of this data do you really need to keep on the ViewState?" For example, is there enough information in a typical page request to be able to rebuild all of the information that is in some of these controls?

I find that ASP.NET typically uses ViewState far more than I really need it to, and if you're getting a 1MB viewstate, I suspect the same is probably true for you. I highly recommend reading [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate.aspx) to get a more full understanding of how ViewState works, what causes values to get saved to ViewState, and how to avoid using it where it's not necessary. You may be able to solve the bulk of your problem simply by doing more of your work in Page_Init instead of Page_Load, for example.

Comment: how much to i need to keep would depend. saying all that, after reading that article,thanks for link, I think the problem is where data is assigned to the control, after the control is added to the parent control, thus causing unnecessary viewstate persistance,rather than data first, then add to collection. ill try this simple change, and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

You can "share" a ViewState between any number of objects by passing it around as a `StateBag` type, or by using delegate functions that return the `ViewState` that needs to be shared. The usage of this, however; should be limited to very specific circumstances, because typically controls use `Properties` to expose their `ViewState` data to other objects (See the link [@StriplingWarrior](https://stackoverflow.com/users/120955/striplingwarrior) posted [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate.aspx)). That being said, here is some example code:

**User Control: SharedState.ascx**

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="SharedState.ascx.vb" Inherits="TestSite.SharedState" %>
```

**User Control: SharedState.ascx.vb**

```
Public Class SharedState
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

    Public Delegate Function GetStateDelegate() As StateBag

    Public Const SharedValueKey = "The key used to access the ViewState dictionary"

    Public Property GetState() As GetStateDelegate

    ' Different ways to get values
    Public Function GetTypedValue(Of TValue)() As TValue
        Return CTypeDynamic(GetValue(), GetType(TValue))
    End Function

    Public Function GetValue() As Object
        ' Use the delegate to get the view state from the parent
        Return GetState.Invoke()(SharedValueKey)
    End Function

    Public Function GetValue(state As StateBag) As Object
        Return state(SharedValueKey)
    End Function

    '  Different ways to set values
    Public Sub SetTypedValue(Of TValue)(value As TValue)
        Me.SetValue(value)
    End Sub

    Public Sub SetValue(value As Object)
        GetState.Invoke()(SharedValueKey) = value
    End Sub

    Public Sub SetValue(state As StateBag, value As Object)
        state(SharedValueKey) = value
    End Sub

    ' Set ViewState value using a key and the delegate
    Public Sub SetStateWithKey(key As String, value As Object)
        GetState.Invoke()(key) = value
    End Sub

    ' Get ViewState value using a key and the delegate
    Public Function GetStateWithKey(key As String) As Object
        Return GetState.Invoke()(key)
    End Function
End Class
```

**Page: SharedStatePage.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="SharedStatePage.aspx.vb" Inherits="TestSite.SharedStatePage" %>
<%@ Register src="SharedState.ascx" tagname="SharedState" tagprefix="uc1" %>

<uc1:SharedState ID="SharedState1" runat="server" />
<uc1:SharedState ID="SharedState2" runat="server" />
```

**Page: SharedStatePage.aspx.vb**

```
Public Class SharedStatePage
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        ' Set up SharedState 1 & 2 to use the delegate '
        SharedState1.GetState = AddressOf GetState
        SharedState2.GetState = AddressOf GetState

        ' Set the view state from the page '
        ViewState(SharedState.SharedValueKey) = 23

        ' Read the view state from the user controls '
        Dim sharedInt As Integer
        sharedInt = SharedState1.GetTypedValue(Of Integer)()
        sharedInt = SharedState1.GetValue()
        sharedInt = SharedState1.GetValue(ViewState)
        sharedInt = SharedState2.GetValue()

        ' Set the view state from one of the user controls '
        SharedState2.SetTypedValue(Of String)("Hello")
        Dim sharedStr As String = ViewState(SharedState.SharedValueKey)
        sharedStr = SharedState1.GetTypedValue(Of String)()
        sharedStr = SharedState2.GetValue()

        ' Use a different key to set and get view state data '
        ViewState("MyKey") = New With {.Name = "Some Object", .Value = 46}
        Dim myObj = SharedState1.GetStateWithKey("MyKey")

        SharedState2.SetStateWithKey("MyKey", "New Value")
        myObj = ViewState("MyKey")
    End Sub

    Private Function GetState() As StateBag
        Return ViewState
    End Function
End Class
```

Use with caution, or don't use with abandon.